# jQuery load needs to wait for target scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I'm using jQuery.load to get contents of another page on the same domain.
What I need it to do is to wait for the target page to fully load cause the content I want is loaded using ajax on the target page.

I can't figure out how to do that, so therefore I'm asking here.

Anyone who can help me?

```
$('.getjson').load('URL .cso-wspn-cont.cso-tile-view.static ul');
```

The content in the UL is inserted with ajax so my jQuery.load gets an empty UL.

Comment: Maybe post an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MasterYoda added code to my question.

Comment: Im confused, so you want to load a page using the markup from another page that in turn is loaded via AJAX from another page?

Comment: @MasterYoda It's like this: I'm on Page1, on Page2 (same site just another page I don't have controll over) there is a UL-list that I want on Page1. The UL-list on page2 gets populated with items using ajax on pageload so on my .load from page1 gets an empty UL.

Comment: Why not just use the same AJAX request that populates Page2 on Page1?

Comment: @MasterYoda Because thats out of my reach. This is a custom page in a large system I'm trying to build and you can only use your own javascript and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ,

```
$(window).bind("load",function(){
     $('.getjson').load('URL .cso-wspn-cont.cso-tile-view.static ul');
}
```

Or instead of wondow you can give selector of parent div of the div you are using 
 :) :)

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't do any difference.